# Margin Openoffice python

Tags: python, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, uno

I keep searching without any results so i would give it a try here. I'm trying to make a document for OpenOffice with Python.. I just can't find how to set the top margin of the document. Anybody has an idea how to do this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you scripting openoffice, or using tools to create the XML of the ODF files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work for me (in a Python macro context):

```
import uno

def setMargin():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oStyle = doc.StyleFamilies.getByName("PageStyles").getByName("Default")
    oStyle.TopMargin = 5000  #Not sure what the units are
```